# Как-то не так удаляется спам

Tags: поддержка, спам

Есть [сообщение](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/601675/178988) с рейтингом -5, удалённое Духом:

[image: скриншот сообщения]

Я на нём ставил тревогу, которая была признана полезной:

[image: скриншот тревоги]

Так почему же сообщение отображается как обычное удалённое, а не как спам?

[image: скриншот (не)нормального удаления спама]

И пока я скриншотил [второй образец](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/591862/178988), возник вопрос, почему он удалился как спам при -2?

Comment: Надо в шапке крупным шрифтом написать: "только для тех, у кого 10K+ репы".

Comment: @alexolut, я ж всё заскриншотил.

Comment: этого мало для понимания. Ну, по крайней мере, мне.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Причина в том, что этот ответ не был удалён как спам. Он был удалён вместе с ещё двумя аналогичными ответами при уничтожении учётной записи модератором. На ответе было три тревоги «спам», при удалении все они были подтверждены (но для удаления как спама этого было недостаточно).

На образце была одна тревога от участника (-1 от Духа), следом тревога от модератора (ещё -1 от Духа), после которой он был удалён. Для удаления ведь считаются не голоса, а тревоги.

Comment: _"при удалении все они были подтверждены"_ - мне кажется, что в таком случае надо удалять как спам, нет?

Comment: @Qwertiy удаление как спам влечет бан по IP и минус 100 репутации учётке. Представьте,  что ответ просто плохой, а на нем одна тревога "оскорбительный" или "спам" (так часто бывает). При удалении тревога подтвердится, хотя вообще-то она спорная. Но остальные последствия тут точно излишни.

Comment: Имхо, тут модератор мог бы вручную "тревогнуть" один из ответов, чтобы IP заблокировать.

Comment: `-100` учётке, которую уже удалили? Ой, как страшно-то))) А вот ip можно и не банить.